# Element of odd order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x$ be an element of finite order $n$ in a group $G$.

I want to show that if the order $n$ is odd  then $x^i\neq x^{-i}$ for all $i=1,2,..,n-1$.

I think that a way to prove this would be to show that if  $x^i= x^{-i}$, then $i=n$, which is a contradiction.

Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: It's not really a proof by contradiction you'll have, rather a proof by contraposition.

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $x^i=x^{-i}$ then $x^{2i}=e$ so that $n\mid 2i$. If $n$ is odd then this leads to $n\mid i$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If $n \vert i$ then i is a multiple of n, and then we must have $i\geq n$. Is that correct?

Comment: More to the point: it leads to $i\notin\{1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Glad to help. You are very welcome.